# I am trying to create an 8-bit shift register and not quite sure where I'm going wrong

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

```
CHIP Shift8 {
     IN x;
     OUT out[8];

     PARTS:
     DFF(x=x, out=d1);
     DFF(x=d1, out=d2);
     DFF(x=d2, out=d3);
     DFF(x=d3, out=d4);
     DFF(x=d4, out=d5);
     DFF(x=d5, out=d6);
     DFF(x=d6, out=d7);
     DFF(x=d7, out=d8);

     Bit(x=d1,  out=out[0]);
     Bit(x=d2,  out=out[1]);
     Bit(x=d3,  out=out[2]);
     Bit(x=d4,  out=out[3]);
     Bit(x=d5,  out=out[4]);
     Bit(x=d6,  out=out[5]);
     Bit(x=d7,  out=out[6]);
     Bit(x=d8,  out=out[7]);

}
```

`out[8]` never seems to change when I test my code. However, d1-d8 do change as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The usual Nand2Tetris Bit implementation has two inputs, the new value and a load signal which, if true, causes the new value to be loaded into the Bit; otherwise the Bit retains its current value.